# Is it possible in playframework to override the default save action in the CRUD controller and redirect to list after

Tags: controller, action, playframework

I'm using Play framework's great crud module. The thing is I would like to do some special processing and validation before my object gets saved. So I created a save action in my CRUD controller. So far so good. But now after the object is saved I would like to render the list of objects just like the CRUD module was doing before I overrode its save action. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my controller:

```
package controllers.admin;

import java.util.List;

import models.Category;
import controllers.CRUD;

@CRUD.For(Category.class)
public class Categories extends CRUD {

     public static void save(Long id, Category category) {
         // Do my custom save process here

         //Redirect to the list page like CRUD was doing before I created this save action
     }

}
```

I tried different things like `parent()` [Deprecated] not what I wanted. I tried `CRUD.list()` but I need to pass parameters which I don't have. I also tried `render(admin/Categories/List.html, ??????);` but I would need to pass a list and I don't know what to call it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right path. At the end just call `redirect(request.controller + ".list");` It should work.

Comment: Thanks Niels! It's exactly what I needed. It works like a charm