# How to get a DateTime input in a Play! CRUD form?

Tags: datetime, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

By default a `java.util.Date` field is represented in a CRUD form as a simple "DATE" input.

```
public class DatedModel extends Model {

    public Date creationDate;
```

in the CRUD admin I see:

```
creationDate           [TEXTINPUT]
                       yyyy-MM-dd format.
```

Is there any way to have a DateTime input instead, on *selected* fields only (not all of them modifying the application.conf `date.format`)?

Is there a way to affect which "widget" is used for a given field in the 'automated' CRUD admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found in the documentation my answer:

You can indeed [customize each field](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/crud#custom); a more extensive example can be found on the lunatech blog using [jquery datatables](http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/01/28/playframework-jquery-datatables) which also shows how to modify pagination.

```
#{crud.table fields:['name', 'company']}

   #{crud.custom 'company'}
     <a href="@{Companies.show(object.company.id)}">
         ${object.company.name}
     </a>
   #{/crud.custom}

#{/crud.table}
```

PS.

@AditSaxena hint was good and indeed a simple solution; but not what I wanted because it's not acceptable that the 'hint' is not correct! Clearly confusing for a user!

So for a datetime input (the specific question) we can combine the annotation (described in the [doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/releasenotes-1.1#play.data.binding.As))

```
 @As(lang={"*"}, value={"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"})
```

with a custom hint, eg.

```
   #{crud.custom 'mydate'}
   <span class="crudHelp">
       Date format: etcetc.
   </span>
     ...
   #{/crud.custom}
```

I'll also point out that you can [write your own validator](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/validation#anamecustomCustomvalidationusingCheckWitha)

Other related useful questions:

- [Is it possible in playframework to override the default save action in the CRUD controller and redirect to list after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415627/)
- [Play! framework CRUD module: adding default values and change date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024080/)
- [Play framework CRUD file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418520/) about custom file upload fields

Answer (score 3):

Something like this in your *application.conf*:

```
module.crud=${play.path}/modules/crud
date.format=yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Then in the *model*:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import play.data.binding.As;
import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
import play.templates.*;
import play.mvc.Scope.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.Logger;
import play.templates.JavaExtensions;

@Entity
public class Product extends Model {
    @As(lang={"*"}, value={"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"}) 
    public Date creationDate;
}
```

Your *controller*:

```
package controllers;
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;
import models.*;

public class Products extends CRUD {
}
```

- [Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/releasenotes-1.1#play.data.binding.As)
- Working demo: https://github.com/saxxi/play-framework-test

Comment: Thanks, but @As gives a `As cannot be resolved to a type` error... what should I import?

Comment: thanks! now I feel a bit stupid... it is of course in the documentation. Though I must say, as usual, that the information is not /that/ easy to find :) !

Comment: Ok, this is not really working as I expected: the "@As" seems to be ignored (with or without time), and only the date.format is used. This means I'm getting time everywhere now... I edited your code, is something else I might be missing?

Comment: Ok, I'm understanding better. The "As" actually works well, but does not affect the 'hint'. The `application.conf` setting affects the hint. Would be nice to be able to link the 'hint' to the 'As'...

Comment: Hi Stefano, in fact for me too is quite difficult to find some info [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/releasenotes-1.1#anamebindingSupportforcustombindinga) is some. (Continues)

Comment: Thanks for going into this whole trouble!!! Starting from your demo, try adding a `@As(lang={"*"}, value={"yyyy-MM-dd"})
    public Date warrantyDate;` field that is supposed to have ONLY a date, not a datetime. The "hint" remains "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format". I wish that that 'widget' would adapt to the '@As'... but it doesn't!

Comment: I thought I'd let you know that I managed to find a solution, by using the #{crud.custom} tag. Might help you too!

Comment: Setting `date.format` in `application.conf` worked for me. Just one correction. You could change the format from 12 hour to 24 hour format which is the way date is shown in database console. `date.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`